# How to calculate the time?

Tags: ms-access

Using Access 2003 Database

Table

```
EmpID Intime Outtime

001   090020   180000
002   060000   220000
003   030040   231020
```

So on…,

InTime and Outime Column Data type is Text.

```
090000 - hhmmss
```

Here I want to calculate the time like 090000 to 180000 is the office time, Remaining time is over duty time.

Expected Output

```
EmpID Intime Outtime WorkedTime OverdutyTime

001    090020 180000   080040
002    060000 220000   090000       070000
003    030040 231020   090000       101040
```

So on…,

It Should Display only 9 Hour in Worked time column, remaining comes to overduty time column.

Need Query Help

Comment: You mean "using Jet database."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you need:

```
SELECT Format(IIf(CLng(OutTime) > 180000, CDate("18:00:00"), 
       CDate(Format(OutTime, "00:00:00"))) - IIf(CLng(InTime) < 90000, 
       CDate("09:00:00"), CDate(Format(InTime, "00:00:00"))), "hh:nn:ss") 
       As WorkedTime, 
       Format(IIf(CLng(InTime) < 90000, CDate("09:00:00") - 
       CDate(Format(InTime, "00:00:00")), 0) + IIf(CLng(OutTime) > 180000, 
       CDate(Format(OutTime, "00:00:00")) - CDate("18:00:00"), 0), "hh:nn:ss") 
       As OverdutyTime
FROM Table
```

I have broken up the lines for ease of reading.

I think there may be an error in your calculation in this line:

```
003    030040 231020   090000       101040
```

Comment: @Remou - But in the calculation, there is an error. EmpID, Intime, Outtime, WorkedTime, OverdutyTime --> 1180  08:36:28 08:37:23 00:22:37 00:23:32 - Here Worktime is displaying wrongly. It should display 00:00:00. 
1240 08:58:09 08:58:09 00:01:51 00:01:51 - Here also Worktime is displaying wrongly. It should display 00:00:00. 
1202 19:04:00 19:04:00 01:04:00 01:04:00 - Here also Worktime is displaying wrongly. It should display 00:00:00. Please can You check this error.

Comment: @Remou - If Emp is PunchingIn after 09:00:00 before 18:00:00 work time is diplaying correctly. If Emp Is PunchingIn Before 09:00:00 after 18:00:00 Worktime is displaying wrongly. How to solve this error.